# Simple FPGA serial communication not working

Tags: uart, rs232, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

[FPGA board](http://www.altera.co.uk/education/univ/materials/boards/de2-115/unv-de2-115-board.html) ([manual](ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Altera_Material/12.1/Boards/DE2-115/DE2_115_User_Manual.pdf))

[USB-to-RS232 cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIf1v.jpg) ([controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIf1v.jpg))

[synthesis reports](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzyfosnk0o7jqsq/output_files.zip)

I created a simple [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBxte.png) which shorts the TXD and RXD pins according to the manual. However, when I use [RealTerm](http://realterm.sourceforge.net/) to send some data it seems that the result is not [displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5IN3.png) at all (nothing is received on the PC). `TXD` is `PIN_G9` and `RXD` is `PIN_G12` but I have tried switching them to no avail.

I have made sure the protocol settings are the same through the [Device Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lTHA.png) and RealTerm. What else can I be missing? I'm starting to think there is something wrong with the cable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed a faulty cable. I used another one and it works.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you forgot to load the .qsf file in the Quartus project so that the fitter does not really know what pins you are referring to. Check this, check also that your adapter is working short circuiting the tx and rx pins manually, check that the correct COM port is opened in RealTerm. Your settings look good, just keep in mind that they don't mind at all if you just make a short circuit, as long as you don't use flow control.

If none of the above helps please post the compiler/fitter full report.

Comment: I'm not sure how to short them because the CTS signal is off when it's unplugged. I have added the full report to the post. This is my first time working with interfaces so I'm pretty sure it's some stupid connection issue.

Comment: Your report looks quite good to me. You said you swapped TX and RX so we can rule that out too (be extra sure about that). I'd say your adapter is next. Can you please elaborate the "I don't know how to test" part? What CTS are you referring to? Flow control is disabled, CTS should not be a concern at all.

Comment: I shorted the second and third pins (on the wide side) with a screwdriver and still nothing is being displayed on RealTerm. Bear in mind this is my first time using that terminal, and I don't even know how it should look like when it's working.

Comment: Here is a video: https://www.mediacru.sh/zeJwvO7JuVFf

 (sorry for the lack of shorting equipment)

Comment: Is the screwdriver shorting against the metal shield?

Comment: @Majenko Nope. Tried it again with a finer blade. I haven't seen it work once.

Comment: Can you please try with putty too? That's another serial terminal emulator.

Comment: It was indeed a faulty cable. I replaced it with another one and it works instantly.